# In how many ways can you partition a list?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I have a list (not sure what to call it) $L$ containing $n$ elements $e_i^{[k]}$ where $[k]$ is a natural number that indicates a group label for any given element and the lower index $i$ is an index given to distinguish elements from each other. The list might look something like the following  $L = [ e_0^{[0]}, e_1^{[2]}, e_2^{[0]}, e_3^{[1]} ] $.

**The question is**, in how many ways is it possible to partition an arbitrary list (i.e. group the elements) on the **conditions:**

$i)$ Only elements with the same group label $[k]$ may be partitioned together.

$ii)$ We only consider positions where an element is moved from right to left, so for instance $L_1$ is feasible whereas $L_2$ is not because element $e_0^{[0]}$ moved from left to right.

So in the **example** above the answer is one ($L_1$ is the solution):

$L_1 = [ [e_0^{[0]}e_2^{[0]}], e_1^{[2]}, e_3^{[1]} ] $

$L_2 = [ e_1^{[2]}, [e_0^{[0]}e_2^{[0]}], e_3^{[1]} ] $

The position between groups is considered but not the position within groups and we don't consider cases where no change has been done at all, i.e. $L$ itself doesn't count. Moreover it is not necessary for all elements with the same group label $[k]$ to be grouped, i.e. we consider all combinations.

**Possible solution:**

I'm guessing maybe this could be solved by using Stirling numbers of the second kind somehow. If we count all the elements that correspond to a specific label $[k]$ we can solve that sub-problem with Stirling numbers. Maybe we can combine the solutions to each sub-problem and get the total?

Comment: Given your example, it seems to me you expressed the problem poorly. It seems you didn't just mean "only elements with the same group label can be partitioned together", but also "elements with the same group label *must* be partitioned together". No?

Comment: My apologies, I made some mistakes in the problem description that are now corrected. Also, regarding your question; it is not a condition for all elements to be grouped. If you think this is still poorly expressed I'll put in an example that demonstrates this also.